# List of availables styles for python-docx table

Tags: python, python-docx

Is there a way to display all the available table styles when working with python-docx ?

In the example below i'm using the 'Table Grid' style but I would like to explore more styles.

```
from docx import Document
doc = Document()

table = doc.add_table(rows=3, cols=3)
table.style = 'Table Grid'
table.autofit = False
table.allow_autofit = False
for row in table.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
        cell.width = Pt(100)
table.cell(0, 0).text = 'Name'
table.cell(0, 1).text = 'Age'
table.cell(0, 2).text = 'City'
for i, data in enumerate([('Alice', '25', 'New York'), ('Bob', '30', 'San Francisco'), ('Charlie', '22', 'Los Angeles')], start=1):
    table.cell(i, 0).text = data[0]
    table.cel(i, 1).text = data[1]
    table.cell(i, 2).text = data[2]

doc.save('example_document.docx')
```

I'm missing the way of displaying all the style possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like a list is available here : https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html#table-styles-in-default-template

But you can't see the corresponding result directly, you'll need to write a loop to generate a table for each style.